# Mountain Lion Figlet through MacPorts error?

Tags: terminal, macos, macports

I've just installed Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.4.1 + command line tools, and MacPorts for ML.

It's working for other packages but I can't get figlet to install.

When I use `sudo port install figlet` in the terminal it stops quickly and outputs:

```
--->  Building figlet
Error: org.macports.build for port figlet returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port figlet for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_figlet/figlet/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port figlet failed
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what to look for in the log

Comment: I don't see any recent activity for `figlet` in MacPorts tracker. Only looking at the log will help.  Can you post it to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com)--or something of the like--and link it in your question?

Comment: heres the log: http://pastebin.com/W65fsC83

Comment: I noticed that in ML, Xcode doesn't create a 'Developer' directory, it holds everything in the Xcode app in the Applications folder. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: XCode in ML is the same as Lion in that respect. I'm running ML and have no trouble installing `figlet`.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling the command line tools and see if that helps

Comment: I retracted a previous comment regarding the CL tools.  That might be the issue if you are having trouble installing other ports. I'm going to look at the package's makefile to see what's up as well. If you've installed the CL tools, the problem could be there.

Comment: I re-installed CL tools, rebooted, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4466/discussion-between-ephsmith-and-jack-stewart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by cleaning the port with

```
sudo port clean figlet
```

then installing using

```
sudo port install figlet
```

According to the Macports [ProblemHotList](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/ProblemHotlist), this error is typical of existing packages that have stored compiler locations that aren't current. Cleaning the package and reinstalling assures the package is rebuilt with the current compiler collection settings for MacPorts.

Comment: Cleaning and trying again is the first thing you should always try anytime any MacPorts port fails to build, especially when the words "Skipping completed" are present in the main.log which indicate that the build attempt was not from a clean slate.